# Extending efficient PAC learning with classification noise to statistical query model with unlabeled random draws for axis-aligned rectangles in $R^2$

Tags: machine-learning, pac-learning

I have proven that if $C$, a concept class, is efficiently learnable from statistical queries using $H$, a representation class over $X$, then $C$ is efficiently PAC learning using $H$ in the presence of classification noise.

How would I extend this result to a statistical query model where the learning algorithm, in addition to the oracle $STAT(c, D)$, is also given access to unlabeled random draws from the target distribution $D$ and that the concept class of axis-aligned rectangles in $R^2$ can be efficiently learned in this paradigm?

*I saw this problem online, but it seems to original in Kearns–Vazirani.*